# MEF, IOC or Prism? Best approach to develop Silverlight client to RIA Services

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, prism, mef, wcf-ria-services

I need to get correct decision for the long-term project about what to choose:
 MEF, IOC or Prism.

Which is the best approach to develop Silverlight website (RIA Services).

Basically it has complex UI.

Thank you for any clue!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let's put it like this:

IOC is a pattern
MEF is a library from Microsoft that helps you manage things and things "you don't know about" where IOC is about managing things you do know about

PRISM - is a library that was designed to assist in building complex UI. It does use MEF or Unity (your choice) as dependency container.

Therefore, your questions doesn't really make sense the way it is asked. If you want to build complex UI with silverlight then you do want to invest into learning PRISM. PRISM, in turn, will use MEF (or Unity)

Comment: I would add that MEF won't really help you to use things you don't know about. (As you won't be able to do anything useful with contracts -ie interfaces- you don't know about.). MEF is a dependncy container designed to help with extensibility scenarios. Dependency Injecters, like MEF, Unity or Autofac are often used when implementing IoC (Inversion of Control)

Comment: Yes, in most real-world scenarios you won't use "things you don't know about". But even PRISM modularity with MEF is completely "loose". You can put modules on server as files and load them up on demand. More about MEF: http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/ten-reasons-to-use-managed.html

Comment: Yes I agree. But I meant that if you load through mef components about which your app don't know anything, you won't be able to do anything with them, because the registration interfaces will be meaningless to your app. And apps are stupid. ;) I think we agree in fact.